# What is "Data()" in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

(This took me a long time to debug, and so I am trying to understand what is going on better.)

Why does the first line work, and the second one does not?

```
$("#cardType").data('kendoComboBox').value(newValue);
$("#cardType").val(newValue);
```

What is the .data('kendoComboBox') doing exactly?

`console.log($("#cardType").data('kendoComboBox') )` returns:

```
Object { ns=".kendoComboBox", element={...}, _events={...}, more...}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/data -- it retrieves a variable attached to the element. We can't tell you what that code is doing, *exactly,* because we don't know what's stored there.

Comment: `[object Object]` Really? Do you really debug this in IE?

Comment: Sorry, yes that was IE. I rerun in FireFox.

Comment: Ok, now: do you see a `value` method anywhere in that object after you view `more...`?

Comment: Yes, there is such a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `value()` methods defined for jQuery objects - it's [**.val()**](https://api.jquery.com/val/). And it only makes sense for the form elements to be used on - `input`, `textarea` and so on.

But there's [**.data()**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method which allows to store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements. When used with a single argument, it's a getter - and it can return any object previously stored by the given key.

Apparently, `$("#cardType")` element has a [**Kendo UI combobox**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox) widget attached to it. When attached, this widget stores the reference to itself within the element's dataset - that's a common behavior for widgets; actually, jQuery UI uses the same approach.

If an element is wrapped with some visual representation of combobox, it will no longer be shown to a user - so any attempt to set its value directly won't be exposed. What should be used is `.value()` method of a combobox widget ([doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#methods-value)). That's why the second snippet didn't work - it actually has changed that value, but didn't let widget know about it.

Comment: But how is that returning the correct object?  I am not setting it anywhere.

Comment: Yes, he is right, it does return the correct object.

Comment: @GregHollywood Add the result of `console.log( $("#cardType").data('kendoComboBox') )` to the question, please.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry if my remarks sound a bit... snide. ) But I really really don't understand why one debugs - trying to understand things! - in IE, really. ) Both Firefox and Chrome are far better tools for that.